# Correlation analysis using a case-control study-based data

Tags: continuous-data, case-control-study

I have a case-control study-based data.
This is a data to confirm the association of hypertension and BMI.
The definition of the case group (hypertension group) is SBP(systolic blood pressure)>=140.
The definition of the control group (healthy group) is SBP<120.

I have a question.
If I would like to confirm the association of hypertension or SBP is associated with BMI, should I assess the association of SBP with BMI rather than the association of hypertension with BMI?
Because SBP is a continuous vairable, and is more informative than a case-control label.

Is this idea right?
If it is not right, could you tell me why it is not right?

Comment: Do you have any other variables apart from SBP and BMI ? Are participants measured only once ?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I have other clinical variables.

In this question, I would like to know whether it is appropriate that a correlation analysis of continuous variable, which was used for definition of the case-control label, was perfomred using the case-control study based data.

Comment: Yes, you can do that, but if you have other variables you should not, since it could well be biased and other variables might be confounders, or competing exposures. You might also want to account for differential baseline values.

Comment: Thank you for your further comment. In my case-control data, case and control samples were collected from different cohorts. The case samples were collected from a hospital-based cohort. The control samples were collected from a population-based cohort. In that case, is it appropriate that a correlation analysis is performed using the case-control study based data?